# Почему не работает магический метод __div__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from __future__ import division
class BaseWallet:

    def __init__(self, name, amount, exchange_rate=1):
        self.name = f'{name}'
        self.amount = amount
        self.exchange_rate = exchange_rate

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, BaseWallet):
            new_amount = self.amount + other.amount * other.exchange_rate/self.exchange_rate
        else:
            new_amount = self.amount + float(other)
        return BaseWallet(self.name, new_amount, self.exchange_rate)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, BaseWallet):
            new_amount = self.amount - other.amount * other.exchange_rate/self.exchange_rate
        else:
            new_amount = self.amount - float(other)
        return BaseWallet(self.name, new_amount, self.exchange_rate)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        new_amount = self.amount * float(other)
        return BaseWallet(self.name, new_amount, self.exchange_rate)

    def __div__(self, other):
        new_amount = self.amount / float(other)
        return BaseWallet(self.name, new_amount, self.exchange_rate)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return BaseWallet.__mul__(self, other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return BaseWallet.__add__(self, other)

class RubleWallet(BaseWallet):
    coef = 1

    def __init__(self, name, amount, exchange_rate=coef):
        self.name = f'{name}'
        self.amount = amount
        self.exchange_rate = exchange_rate


class DollarWallet(BaseWallet):
    coef = 60

    def __init__(self, name, amount, exchange_rate=coef):
        self.name = f'{name}'
        self.amount = amount
        self.exchange_rate = exchange_rate


class EuroWallet(BaseWallet):
    coef = 70

    def __init__(self, name, amount, exchange_rate=coef):
        self.name = f'{name}'
        self.amount = amount
        self.exchange_rate = exchange_rate


ob1 = RubleWallet("X", 70)
ob2 = EuroWallet("D", 10)
ob2 = ob2/5
print(ob2.name, ob2.amount, ob2.exchange_rate)
```

Скину весь код программы, потому что его обычно тут просят сразу же. Как видим, реализовано куча магических методов, обозначающих арифметические действия. Внимание на метод **div**. Все методы нормально работают, но только не он. Pycharm его не выделяет розовеньким, как все остальные методы. Он просто не определяется как метод. При выполнении строчек, которые написаны внизу, выдает такую ошибку:

```
D:\Documents\Pycharm\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Documents/Pycharm/task10.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents/Pycharm/task10.py", line 66, in <module>
    ob2 = ob2/5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'EuroWallet' and 'int'
```

Я гуглил, везде написано, что метод **div** есть в питоне. Но мой питон его не понимает.
Версия питона 3.8. Версия pycharm:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Метод `__div__` был только во втором питоне. В третьем питоне внесли определённые изменения в механику деления, и вместо этого метода теперь нужно использовать `__truediv__`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что надо использовать метод [`__truediv__()`](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/peregruzka-operatorov.html).